# GUI builder for web apps

Tags: java, user-interface, wysiwyg

What is the best GUI builder for web apps (any language) that can hook into the backend code, in that it is compatible with dynamically generated web pages and can submit Ajax requests?

As a side note, is there such a GUI builder for java based web apps (i.e. Play Framework)

I'm kinda looking for something similar to Interface Builder for Iphone and Android, but for web apps.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Real developers don't care as long as it gets the job done adequately...

Comment: Yes they do - because using those tools often results in a horrible pile of crap.

Answer (score 7):

For such a task I would recommend [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home), which has a beautiful and complete [widgetset](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler), with great [documentation](https://vaadin.com/book). Moreover, you can extend, restyle existing widgets or create custom ones.

If you use eclipse you can install a [plugin](http://vaadin.com/eclipse) that helps designing UIs - but in my opinion this won't be needed once you get used to the development style ;)

If you like desktop development style, you will love Vaadin. You will only have to code in Java, and the published product will be html+css+js (ajax)+java.

I've worked with this framework and found it very promising, and easy to use - of course it has its learning curve, but once you get used to it, and have a well structured project, you can implement new features easily.

Note that Vaadin is based on [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/), so if can't find an appropriate widget for your app among the many included in the framework, you might find GWT knowledge to come handy.